# PDF manipulation

Tags: javascript, php, pdf

I would like to ask you a question please. I’m discussing one project with potential client and they have a bit of specific request. They want a system for ordering and printing jobs and one section of this system requires certain PHP manipulation. They would like to use a PDF template as one layer, allow user to define text (in a certain size, font type and colour) as another layer and then combine this into a single printable PDF.

Or it could be even in .ai Adobe Illustrator format but I am not aware of any technology that could do this, hence my suggestion with PDF.

Do you know of any technology, library or maybe even JavaScript library that could take PDF base template and then add customisable text on it and create PDF output?

Comment: Here's a doc on one way to do it. http://www.antennahouse.com/XSLsample/howtoRC/Howtodevelop-en-2a.pdf https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/

Comment: What you're discussing with the client is likely a Web2Print system of some sort. If you Google the net for that term you'll find about 300000 results; there are literally hundreds of potential solutions for what you need that have been developed already. I would suggest you find someone who has knowledge of print and publishing and discuss this with them before blindly blundering into this potential project :)

Answer (score 1):

If you can do it in PHP, there are [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/) (which I used quite heavily without any problems) or [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/).
Pretty powerful and very easy to use.

UPDATE:
I just remembered [this library, FPDI](http://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/about/): I never used it, but looks like it probably do exactly what you need.

*(But I now doubt I understood your question properly, because with a simple Google search you can find those very easily...Did I miss something?)*

Comment: I personally prefer HTML2PDF for generating PDFs! I find it has a much better parser for HTML and CSS than TCPDF! But that's just my opinion. Anyway the main point.. I think that he wants to be able to open an existing PDF and edit it. Which as far as I know TCPDF cannot do on its own :( I might be wrong though but that's what I interpreted from the question

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if that is what you want to do but I would create the template with php (for example using fPDF) and then create a tool that would let you edit the template's php allowing you to introduce changes to attributes like number of cells, cell height etc. and generate second PDF that meets your requirements (the final one).

You have to keep in mind there will be many potential problems, for example UTF-8 encoding, if you want to let the users select the font, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could try PDF overlays. There are several PDF libraries that can do this. 
Here is how to do with my company's product: http://www.gnostice.com/nl_article.asp?id=148&t=PDF_Overlay_Stitching_PDF_Pages_Together_in_NET

[image: This image shows two pdf pages that have been overlaid.]