# Combine half pdf page with other

Tags: pdf

I want a pdf tool to unite half pdf page with the other half pdf page

Like this:

[image: Example]

Comment: Sorry but your question is off topic on SO

Comment: Check this answer. It is exactly what you want.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/30159620/1434413

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at the pdfunite utility.  I don't know if it will be able to delete that whitespace like in your example or not.

***pdfunite** merges several PDF (Portable Document Format) files in order of their occurrence on command line to one PDF result file.*

From the man page example:

`pdfunite sample1.pdf sample2.pdf sample.pdf`

*merges all pages from sample1.pdf and sample2.pdf (in that  order)  and creates sample.pdf*

If you are ok with it being rasterized you can use imagemagick as indicated by @tomas and @tiktok answers here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12482/split-pages-in-pdf